# Endless loop to delete files while streaming movie using Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

So I use Emby to stream media to my TV. I was watching the Lotr extended in 4K and apparently, Emby creates 30gb worth of transcoding data while streaming files of such size. So after 30 mins or so, the movie stopped because my hard drive was full.

I created a script dat deletes the files in that specific folder that are older then 5 minutes:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "C:\Users\*myuser*\AppData\Roaming\Emby-Server\programdata\transcoding-temp"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt 
$limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Now, this works fine, but I wanted to automate it because otherwise I'd have to manually run this every 30 minutes. I tried putting it in an endless loop, but that doesn't seem to delete the files:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
$path = "C:\Users\*myuser*\AppData\Roaming\Emby-Server\programdata\transcoding-temp"

while($true){
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt 
    $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Could someone explain to me why the loop doesn't work and what would be an appropriate solution?

Comment: Create a scheduled task to run the script every 30 minutes

Comment: Deleting files while you are iterating over them can lead to inconsistent results. Better separate directory iteration from file OP: `$files = Get-ChildItem ...` and then `$files | Remove-Item -Force`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `$limit` is calculated once at the start.  You need to update `$limit` for each iteration of the loop.  I'd throw in a `Start-Sleep 300` to stop it just doing it endlessly.